# rpm relocate part of prefix

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I create RPMs that install to /opt/mypackage where /opt/mypackage is a relocation set in the RPM spec file using "Prefix: /opt/mypackage" prefix

If the RPM is built and installed on RHEL5 (RPM version 4.4.2.3) the following commands work:

```
rpm -i --relocate /=`pwd`/ mypackage.rpm
rpm -i --relocate /opt=`pwd`/opt mypackage.rpm
rpm -i --relocate /opt/mypackage=`pwd`/opt/mypackage mypackage.rpm
```

However if the RPM is built on installed on RHEL7 (RPM version 4.11.3) then there are problems:

```
path / in package <mypackage> is not relocatable
path /opt in package <mypackage> is not relocatable
```

but relocating /opt/mypackage works correctly.

Note: rpm -i --prefix=/opt/mkpackage works fine in both cases.

So am I correct to believe that "Prefix: " in the RPM sec should allow relocation of any prefix of the path? e.g. Prefix: `/opt/mypackage` allows relocating `/opt/mypackage` `/opt` or `/`

What might I be doing wrong or could this be a bug?

I note that if I use --badreloc everything works. Why is badreloc required here?

Answer (score 0):

All that --badreloc does is override a warning a message if a path that was *NOT* in a Prefix: tag is relocated.

Otherwise all paths in *.rpm are relocatable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a "Prefix" line for each path that you would like to change.

According to http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/relocatable.html:

> The "dir" will usually be something like "/usr", "/usr/local", or
>   "/opt". Every file in your files list must start with that prefix. For
>   example, if you have "Prefix: /usr" and your files list contains
>   "/etc/foo.conf", the build will fail. The fix for this is to put
>
> ```
> Prefix: /usr
> Prefix: /etc
> ```
>
> into the spec file so that the /usr and /etc directories may be relocated 
>   separately when this package is
>   installed.